# Получить список значений поля объектов класса

Tags: c#, классы

Существует некоторый класс

```
class A
{
    field1, field2;
}
```

а также список

```
List<A> list;
```

Можно ли одним действием получить список значений поля объектов класса `A`, входящих в данный список? Проще говоря, могу ли я в одну строчку получить, допустим, список значений поля `field1` у объектов `list[0], list[1], ..., list[n]` без перебора всех объектов списка и составления списка полей вручную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```
 var field1Array = listOfA.Select(x => x.field1).ToArray();
```

Там под капотом много чего, конечно, происходит - но однострочник, как просили)

Магия `LINQ`!

Comment: Отлично, то, что нужно)